# Problem to upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I get this problem when i am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04.

```
[tor apr 23 18:45:46] Jonathan@Whats next?:~$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:19.04.8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
[tor apr 23 18:46:09] Jonathan@Whats next?:~$ do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1 554 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1 344 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1 346 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache
Segmentation fault
[tor apr 23 18:46:50] Jonathan@Whats next?:~$
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Why the -d flag on release day?

Comment: Because 20.04 is not immediately available for 19.10 user. At the time of writing, `do-release-upgrade` still does not propose it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this command before you run `do-release-upgrade -d`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-keyring
```

Comment: Yes, this worked!  Can you explain why `ubuntu-keyring` needs to be reinstalled?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run do-release-upgrade -d with 'sudo'

Comment: You don't need `sudo` because all `do-release-upgrade` does is checks if a release upgrade exists, and it doesn't install anything.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with 18.04.1 to 20.04. I have tried with and without `sudo`, but still getting error. I have also tried with `update-manager -d`, didn't work.

```
    Checking for a new Ubuntu release
    Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                         
    Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,344 kB]                                                  
    Fetched 1,346 kB in 6s (92.5 kB/s)                                             
    authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
    Authentication failed
    Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt install -f`. This could fix some problems.